# Writing a simple function with foldM and possibly State

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to code a little function that basically iterates through a list of questions, and for every question the prompt will wait for the user's response and add 1 to the score if the answer is correct, do nothing if it is wrong.

I think using foldM should suffice if I only need to keep track of the score, but I'd like to also print for every question its position on the list, like "Question number 1:" and so on.

Would using the State Monad be helpful to keep track of both score and position?
Besides, I'd love to get some practice with State..

Here's the current code:

Every question is a tuple with a string and the answer

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Exit


qs =
    [( "question"
     ,["1"]            --number of the correct answer, from 1 to 4
    ]

main =
    putStrLn "Type \"init\" to begin" >>
    getLine >>= \l -> case l of
        "init" -> act
        _      -> main

act :: IO ()
act =
    let score = foldM (
        \acc (q,a) ->
        putStrLn q >>
        getLine >>= \l ->
        if (l `elem` a)
            then putStrLn "CORRECT!"    >>
                 threadDelay (2 * 10^6) >>
                 acc >>= \a -> a + 1
            else putStrLn "WRONG!"      >>
                 threadDelay (2 * 10^6) >>
                 acc
    ) 0 qs
    in  putStrLn $ "Score: " ++ score >>
    if (score > 18)
        then putStrLn "Bravo!"    >>
        else putStrLn "Not enough!" >>
    putStrLn "Type \"1\" to restart, anything else to quit" >>
    getLine >> \l -> case l of
        "1" -> act
        _   -> exitSuccess
```

Comment: You could do it with State if you were not having IO. You could as an exercise transform all your code into pure code, by let's say replace the interactive getLine by just providing a list of answer. If you want to use State and IO you'll need to use StateT (a monad transformer : I would recommend to do write the pure version first).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `StateT` to allow for both `State` and `IO`.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State

type Question = (String,String)
type Questions = [Question]
type Score = Int
type Game = StateT Score IO ()  -- combine State and IO effects

play :: Question -> Game
play (question,answer) = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn question  -- IO requires using the liftIO function explicitly
  input <- liftIO $ getLine
  if answer == input
    then do
      liftIO $ putStrLn "correct!"
      modify (+1) -- add 1 to score
    else
      liftIO $ putStrLn "wrong!"
  score <- get
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Your score is: " ++ (show score)

questions :: Questions
questions = [("1+1=", "2"), ("What is the best programming language?", "haskell")]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  runStateT (traverse play questions) 0  -- no need for foldM since we're using State to handle the score
  putStrLn "game over"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things if you extract out the iteration function by itself:

```
import Control.Monad

go score (question,answer) = do
  putStr $ question ++ "? "
  response <- getLine
  if response /= answer
    then do putStrLn "Wrong!"
            return score
    else do putStrLn "Right!"
            return (score+1)

questions = [ ("1+1=", "2"), ("2+2","4"), ("What is your favorite color", "\n") ]

doit = foldM go 0 questions
```

If you want to keep track of more state - like the number of questions asked:

```
go (score,n) (question,answer) = do
  putStr $ "#" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ question ++ "? "
  response <- getLine
  if response /= answer
    then do putStrLn "Wrong!"
            return (score,n+1)
    else do putStrLn "Right!"
            return (score+1,n+1)
```